# Force jQuery to not register $

Tags: javascript, jquery

I know there exists a command like jQuery.noConflict. But for this it first registers $, then un-registers it afaik.

I want to edit the jQuery 1.3.2 code to stop it from registering the $ in the first place. I know its not the best of ideas, but I need this in a particular project. Am just not sure how it can be done? I mean what part of jquery.js should I edit/remove? Also, how can I rename jQuery to say jQ from the start itself?

Thank you for your time. Would like any pointers.

I think I need to delete the following from the jQuery code (for 1.4.2):

```
// Expose jQuery to the global object
window.jQuery = window.$ = jQuery;
```

Comment: Why the heck are you doing this? You're almost certainly doing it wrong. After jQuery.noConflict, $ === undefined yields true.

Comment: Just have a look at the source code. Must be in one of the last lines.

Comment: Not clear on why you can't use `noConflict`... could you elaborate?

Comment: If you are using other librairy that needs $, you need to add them after jQuery.

Comment: I have a product which uses jQuery, but in order to ensure that users do not face any conflict with jQuery (as they might have other libraries also), I need to force jQuery to not register $. I also need to change jQuery to say jQueryX to ensure it never conflicts with any other jQuery on the site or any other framework. I am an advanced JS developer so I know what I am doing. I am just wondering if anyone has done this before? or should I manually check the jQuery code?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`noConflict` replaces `$` with the original object, so it doesn't matter that it registers it first.

If you still want to use `$` for jQuery at the same time (so you don't have to write out the long `jQuery`), you can do this:

```
$.noConflict();
jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
  // Code that uses jQuery's $ can follow here.
});
```

Comment: It does matter if he already has an accessor for `$` lacking a setter.

Comment: this is really not the answer i am looking for. i just edited the default jquery code.

Answer (score 0):

I add jQuery.noConflict() to the bottom of my jQuery file. That's usually good enough.